# Division answer not executing properly

Tags: c++, arrays

I am having trouble with the following line of code:

```
double answer;
answer = num[count] / den[count]
cout << " Fraction" << count + 1 << " " << num[count] 
     << " / " << den[count] << " = " << answer << endl;
```

How come my rendition of answer is not working? Am I overlooking something? I am using arrays and am getting the data from a separate text file. When I use the code above I get the numbers that are to be divided correctly but the answer is incorrect. It comes out to be a random number usually 0 or 1.

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;
void read_data(int num[], int den[], int size);
void showValues(int num[],int den[], int size);

int main()
{
    const int size1 = 12;
    const int size2 = 12;
    ifstream dataIn;
    int num[12];
    int den[12];

    read_data(num,den,size1);
    cout << "Here are the fractions: " << endl;
    showValues(num,den,size1);

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}

void read_data(int num[], int den[], int size)
{
    ifstream dataIn;
    dataIn.open("walrus.txt");

    if( dataIn.fail() )
         {
        cout << "File does not exist." << endl;
        exit(1);
         }

     int count;
     for ( count = 0; count < size; count++ )
     {
         dataIn >> num[count];
     }

     for (count = 0; count < size; count++)
     {
         dataIn >> den[count];
     }


     dataIn.close();
 }

void showValues(int num[],int den[], int size)
{
    int count;
        for (count = 0; count < size; count++)
        {
            if (den[count] == 0)
            {
                 cout << " Fraction" << count + 1 << " " 
                      << num[count] << " /" << den[count] 
                      << " Is invalid" << endl;
             }
            else
            {
                double answer;
                answer = num[count] / den[count];
             cout << " Fraction" << count + 1 << " " 
                  << num[count] << " / " << den[count] 
                  << " = " << answer << endl;
             }
        }
 }
```

Comment: An [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would help, particularly  the declarations of the arrays.

Comment: Please show ALL relevant code - data types of arrays, etc, and their values.

Comment: Keep in mind that if `num[count]` and `den[count]` are integral types, the division discards any remainder / fractional component, e.g. it will round anything `>= 0` and `< 1` down to `0`, `5/2 = 2` etc..  You probably want to use `double(num[count]) / den[count]`.

Comment: Any reason you read everything before printing anything? You need less space (and gain flexibility) if you process the data immediately.

Comment: @Deduplicator how would I go about doing that? Sorry I am new to c++ and don't know much.

Comment: Read in as you do now, but only for enough for one line of output, calculate, print the line, repeat. You are finished when the file is empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@main `ifstream dataIn;`
You are not using this object

@function read_data :

```
 int count;
 for ( count = 0; count < size; count++ )
 {
     dataIn >> num[count];
 }

 for (count = 0; count < size; count++)
 {
     dataIn >> den[count];
 }
```

Assuming ur file looks like :

```
1 2 23 32 44 // numerators
2 3 1 99 24 // den
```

The proper way to read is :

```
int count = 0;
while( count < size && dataIn >> num[count++] ) // numerators
    ;

count = 0;
while( count < size && dataIn >> den[count++] )
    ;
```

@function showValues :
try changing

```
   double answer;
    answer = num[count] / den[count];
 cout << " Fraction" << count + 1 << " " 
      << num[count] << " / " << den[count] 
      << " = " << answer << endl;
```

to :

```
double answer = static_cast<double>(num[count]) / den[count];
cout << " Fraction" << count + 1 << " " 
     << num[count] << " / " << den[count] << " = " << answer << endl;
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. But could you possibly give me an idea of how static cast makes it work? I'm a little confused as to how it works since I'm a beginner at coding.

Comment: The original code said "divide these two `int`s, and assign the result to this `double`." What you wanted was "convert these two `int`s to `double`s, divide them, and assign the result to this other `double`." The `static_cast` converts one of the `int`s to a `double`, and the compiler converts the other to a `double` in order to do the math.

Answer (score 1):

In C and C++, if you do,

```
double answer = 10 / 3;
```

your answer will be 3. The reason is you have 2 *integers* and an integer division will take place. The resulting output is then implicitly converted into a double. So the steps are,

1. double answer = 10 / 3
2. double answer = 3
3. double answer = 3.0

To fix this, you tell the compiler that you want this to be treated as floating point division.

```
double answer = 10.0 / 3;
```

This works by,

1. double answer = 10.0 / 3
2. double answer = 10.0 / 3.0
3. double answer = 3.33333333...

The compiler will implicitly cast the 3 into a larger double type, 3.0.

So in your code, you have to convert integer division into floating point division by casting at least one of the division arguments into a double.

```
double foo = num[count] / den[count];
```

simply becomes

```
double foo = num[count] / static_cast<double>(den[count]);
```

Alternatively, if one or both of the arrays were of double type, you would not have this problem requiring casts.